# Django saving new record to a table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django

So i basically have a model called Designations that derives foreign keys from 3 other models (curricula, role and staff) and i am trying to save a new record into the Designations model, the code below shows the Designations and Staffs model. However, for the Curriculum and role models i will not be showing as you can assume PK 1 in Curriula and role models will be used as data in the curriculum and role fields in Designation model

```
class Designations(models.Model):
    designation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curricula, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staffs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "arc_designations"
        unique_together = ('curriculum', 'role', 'staff')
        verbose_name_plural = "Designations"
        ordering = ['designation_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s %s (%s)' % (self.role.role_name,
                                     self.curriculum.course_period.course.course_abbreviation,
                                     self.curriculum.module_period.module.module_abbreviation,
                                     self.staff.staff_full_name)

class Staffs(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admission_number = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                        unique=True,
                                        help_text="Enter 5 digits",
                                        validators=[numeric_only, MinLengthValidator(5)])
    staff_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,
                                       help_text="Enter staff's full name",
                                       validators=[letters_only])
    created_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user_add=True,
                                editable=False,
                                related_name="staff_created_by",
                                db_column="created_by")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                      editable=False)
    updated_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user=True,
                                editable=False,
                                related_name="staff_updated_by",
                                db_column="updated_by")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                                      editable=False)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Roles, through='Designations')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "arc_staffs"
        verbose_name_plural = "Staffs"
        ordering = ['staff_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (S%s)' % (self.staff_full_name, self.admission_number)
```

I have made a forms.py to get the admission_number(field in Staffs model)

```
class AssignRolesForm(forms.Form):
    admission_no = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                     attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'aria-describedby': 'add-btn'}))
```

Assuming that when i submit the form i would like for the admission_number entered in the form to reference into the Staffs model then get its PK to be saved into the staff field in Designations then as i said above, for the curriculum and role fields to referece PK 1 of their respective models. How would i write my function in views.py

**edit
I've tried writing out the view as suggested, heres the code below, currently i cant test my project so let me now if its correct

```
@require_POST
def setStaff(request):
    form = AssignRolesForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        Designations.staff = Staffs.objects.filter(admission_number=form.cleaned_data['admission_no'])
        Designations.role = Roles.objects.get(pk=1)
        Designations.curriculum = Curricula.objects.get(pk=1)
        Designations.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: So, give it a chance *yourself* first - implement your **view**, and then ask for assistance, if still needed.

Comment: @dmitryro i tried writing the view function as shown above

Comment: Model names should be singular, by the way. (`Role` instead of `Roles`, `Staff` (or maybe `StaffMember`) instead of `Staffs`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the clean function on forms is probably where you want to put your logic. The django docs have a good example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other